# Extracting a numerical value from .csv files

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, with a column of pathnames. I can access these paths using:

```
for i, p in enumerate(df['path']):
```

I am now however looking to extract a value from each of these output files.

The csv file looks like:

```
# some values 
# some values : some values
# some values : some values
# some values : some values
# some string : the value I want
# some string : some values
```

Is there a way of extracting this value and inserting it into my dataframe?

I believe regex would do the trick. I am just not sure of the exact way. I have some template code which looks like:

```
if re.match(r"something", p):
        df = pd.read_csv(p)
        df.iloc[i, value_column] = the value I want
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was assisted with this question when asked in a more clear context. 
for a line in a csv file.

```
if re.match('# some string\s*:\s*([^\n]+)', line):
                    number = re.match('# some string\s*:\s*([^\n]+)', line).group(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to extract the value from the text/csv using the builtin `split`:

```
def get_value(string):
    array = string.split(": ")  # maybe without the white space
    return array[0] if len(array) == 1 else array[1]

get_value('some values')
# 'some values'
get_value('some string : the value I want')
# 'the value I want'
```

Alternatively, using regex

```
re.sub(r'.*\:\s*(.*)', r'\1', 'some values')
# 'some values'
re.sub(r'.*\:\s*(.*)', r'\1', 'some string : the value I want')
# 'the value I want'
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I may be misunderstanding, but wouldn't this require me to know what the value in the csv is? I know the value's location but not what the value is.